# not able to split english text from arabic text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on some module where I needed to grab the text from `html` `select` box and place the split text in further two text boxes(one for arabic and other for english).

HTML SELECT box contains a text similar to "عربى::::arabic". Now when I tried to split this whole text from "::::" I got values on both indexs. But while placing them in textboxes, I was only able to place 0th i.e. عربى text. I wasn't able to paste english value to english textbox. HTML select box and textboxes picture:

**JS code**

```
function process() {
              var x = $("#categoryNameId option:selected").text();
              var values =  x.split("::::");
              alert(values[0]);
              alert(values[1]);

              document.getElementById("categoryNameArId").value=values[0]; // arabic textbox
              document.getElementById("categoryNameId").value=values[1]; // english textbox

            }
```

Is there any way to paste splited English value to a textbox meant for English.

Comment: Does the alert work correctly? Does that show you what you expect? Are there any console errors?

Comment: The split seems to be working for both languages, I suggest that you inspect the english element in developer tool and check the CSS which might cause an issue here.

Comment: The problem is not in splitting. I am assuming is binding issue.

Comment: guys sorry to waste your time.. I'll delete this question. It was duplicate ID issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have duplicate id for `categoryNameId`, with duplicate id javascript will get first element found.

so you need change id for select tag

```
<form:select id="categoryNameId" path="categoryName">
```

Comment: Yes bro!, I got it. Thanks for noticing .. I copy pasted that code from elsewhere.. sorry again to waste your time

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the options because i was stuck with it to.

First you have to get the selected Index and then pass it to the split function then it will split the text.

Hope this will help you !!!

Thank You !!!

```js
    function process() {

        var x = document.getElementById('aaaa')
        
        console.log(x.options[x.selectedIndex].text)
        var values = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text.split("::::");
        alert(values[0]);
        alert(values[1]);
    }
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="aaaa" onchange="process()">
    <option>عربى::::arabic</option>
    <option>عربى::::arabic</option>
    <option>عربى::::arabic</option>
    <option>عربى::::arabic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Saad Bhai, it was duplicate ID related issue. Sorry for wasting your time.